# Is there a way you can produce an output like this in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a column which I translate the values using a case statements and I get numbers like this below. There are multiple columns I need to produce the result like this and this is just one column.
[image]

How do you produce the output  as a whole like this below.
The 12 is the total numbers counting from top to bottom
49 is the Average.
4.08 is the division 49/12.
1 is how many 1's are there in the output list above. As you can see there is only one 1 in the output above
8.33% is the division and percentage comes from 1/12 * 100
and so on. Is there a way to produce this output below?
[image]

```
drop table test111
create table test111
(
Q1 nvarchar(max)
);

INSERT INTO TEST111(Q1)
VALUES('Strongly Agree')
,('Agree')
,('Disagree')
,('Strongly Disagree')
,('Strongly Agree')
,('Agree')
,('Disagree')
,('Neutral');

SELECT
CASE WHEN [Q1] = 'Strongly Agree' THEN 5
WHEN [Q1] = 'Agree' THEN 4
WHEN [Q1] = 'Neutral' THEN 3
WHEN [Q1] = 'Disagree' THEN 2
WHEN [Q1] = 'Strongly Disagree' THEN 1
END AS 'Test Q1'
FROM test111
```

Comment: Please avoid posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you please provide T-SQL code examples?

Comment: Maybe check if the aggregation functions like [COUNT, SUM, AVG](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp) and [MIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp) are useful for you. Also check [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Comment: Can you please send some code examples?

Comment: You should be able to do that with a select

Comment: It isn't clear what result you actually expect. Are you asking how to calculate the pixels for `8.33%` or how to create a column that can be an integer, a decimal and a string?

Comment: You normally do that in your front end, not as part of your query.

Comment: I just want to calculate and produce a result like in the screen shot above. I explained in detail if you read above. I just want to write a T-SQL Script to produce the result in the second screen shot above.

Comment: Your code is not counting how many 1's, 2's, 3's, 4's and 5's are in the result set. Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind. I adjusted your code and added more variables for each and it works fine. But can you please explain your code from top to bottom?

Answer (score 0):

I have to make a few assumptions here, but it looks like you want to treat an output column like a column in a spreadsheet. You have 12 numbers. You then have a blank "separator" row. Then a row with the number 12 (which is the count of how many numbers you have). Then a row with the number 49, which is the sum of those 12 numbers. Then the 4.08 row, which is rougly the average, and so on.

Some of these outputs can be provided by `cube` or `rollup`, but neither is a complete solution.

If you wanted to produce this output directly from TSQL, you would need to have multiple `select` statements and combine the results of all of those statements using `union all`. First you would have a `select` just to get the numbers. Then you would have a second `select` which outputs a "blank". Then another `select` which is providing a `count`. Then another `select` which is providing a `sum`. And so on.

You would also no longer be able to output actual numbers, since a "blank" is not a number. Visually it's best represented as an empty string. But now your output column has to be of datatype char or varchar.

You also have to make sure rows come out in the correct order for presentation. So you need a column to order by. You would have to add some kind of ordering column "manually" to each of the `select` statements, so when you union them all together you can tell SQL in what order the output should be provided.

So the answer to "can it be done?" is technically "yes". But if you think seems like a whole lot of laborious and inefficient TSQL work, you'd be right.

The real solution here is to change your approach. SQL should not be concerned with "output formatting". What you should do is just return the actual data (your 12 numbers) from SQL, and then do all of the additional presentation (like adding a blank row, adding a count row, etc), in the code of the program that is calling SQL to get that data.

Comment: @ allmhuran . Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have a basic sample script but just for one column and I have multiple answer columns but I need to get the first one right before I can move on to the next ones. Can you please provide some example Scripts? I have a basic one here which you can build upon.  I will post in the the original post above

Comment: @Charlieface - Can you please explain this step by step. I'm having hard time understanding this piece. SELECT v.TestQ1
FROM RolledUp r
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT r.TestQ1, 0 AS ordering
    WHERE r.grouping = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT v.value, v.ordering
    FROM (VALUES
        (NULL    , 1),
        (r.count , 2),
        (r.sum   , 3),
        (r.avg   , 4),
        (r.one   , 5),
        (r.onePct, 6)
    ) v(value, ordering)
    WHERE r.grouping = 1
) v

Answer (score 0):

I must say, this is one of the strangest T-SQL requirements I've seen, and is really best left to the presentation layer.

It is possible using `GROUPING SETS` though. We can use it to get an extra rollup row that aggregates the whole table.

Once you have the rollup, you need to unpivot the totalled row (identified by `GROUPING() = 1`) to get your final result. We can do this using `CROSS APPLY`.

This is impossible without a row-identifier. I have added `ROW_NUMBER`, but any primary or unique key will do.

```sql
WITH YourTable AS (
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn,
CASE WHEN [Q1] = 'Strongly Agree' THEN 5
WHEN [Q1] = 'Agree' THEN 4
WHEN [Q1] = 'Neutral' THEN 3
WHEN [Q1] = 'Disagree' THEN 2
WHEN [Q1] = 'Strongly Disagree' THEN 1
END AS TestQ1
FROM test111
),
RolledUp AS (
    SELECT
      rn,
      TestQ1,
      grouping = GROUPING(TestQ1),
      count = COUNT(*),
      sum = SUM(TestQ1),
      avg = AVG(TestQ1 * 1.0),
      one = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ1 = 1 THEN 1 END),
      onePct = COUNT(CASE WHEN TestQ1 = 1 THEN 1 END) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(
        (rn, TestQ1),
        ()
    )
)
SELECT v.TestQ1
FROM RolledUp r
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT r.TestQ1, 0 AS ordering
    WHERE r.grouping = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT v.value, v.ordering
    FROM (VALUES
        (NULL    , 1),
        (r.count , 2),
        (r.sum   , 3),
        (r.avg   , 4),
        (r.one   , 5),
        (r.onePct, 6)
    ) v(value, ordering)
    WHERE r.grouping = 1
) v
ORDER BY
  v.ordering,
  r.rn;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6bdba40306347421c98014caebde4d54)

Comment: @ Charlieface -- Can you please explain your code?

Comment: Also the GROUPING does not work on more than one argument. I'm running the code for multiple columns for the table but not just one. Any ideas?

Comment: Have added a bit more explanation. You didn't ask for two columns, but yes sure it is possible, you just need to add it into the relevant points in the query, see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0de9a3d3e1c2337550510bb43cbf8c84